# parse scripts and link tags via regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying this regex..
but not getting the desired result in code..

```
<script[\s\w="'/]*src\s*=\s*['"]([\w/\.\d\s-]*)["']>|<link[/\s\w="\d]*href=['"]([\.\d\w\\/-]*)['"][\s\w="'/]*>
```

here is my pattern..

```
string pattern = @"<script\s[\d\s\w='";
pattern += "\"/]*";
pattern += @"src\s*=\s*['" + "\"]";
pattern += @"([\w/\.\d\s-]*)['" + "\"]>";
pattern += "|";
pattern += @"<link[/\s\w=\d" + "\"]*";
pattern += "href['\"](" + @"[\.\d\w/"+ Regex.Escape("\\") + "-]*)";
pattern += "['\"]" + @"[\s\w='/" + "\"]*>";
```

Just incase you find the fault.. that why its not working well in C#
while the test are all cleared on link given below:
http://regexr.com/3admv

Just to be sure, here is the code:

```
string url = "http://www.uok.edu.pk";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string html = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Regex regex = new Regex(GetDirectoryListingRegexForUrl(url));
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(html);
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("***************");
                    Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());

                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you can help me, please give me the *string pattern* to correctly parse the html I gave in the [link](http://regexr.com/3admv).
I cant seem to get link href via this regex.
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Do not use regex for this. Read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape quote characters here by doubling them:

```
string pattern = @"<script[\s\w=""'/]*src\s*=\s*['""]([\w/\.\d\s-]*)[""']>|<link[/\s\w=""\d]*href=['""]([\.\d\w\\/-]*)['""][\s\w=""'/]*>";

        TextReader reader = File.OpenText("texttoparse.txt");// I put text from your example in this file
        string txt = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var matches = Regex.Matches(txt, pattern);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            if (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("***************");
                Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());

            }
        }
```

output (same as in your RegExr test):

```
***************
<link rel="import" href="component.html" >
***************
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
***************
<script src="js/script.js">
***************
<link rel="import" href="component.html">
***************
<link href="css/style-original.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
***************
<link href="css/style-original.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
***************
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js">
***************
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cufon-yui.js">
***************
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/arial.js">
***************
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chilli.js">
***************
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cycle.js">
***************
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/functions.js">
***************
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox.js">
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you were trying to just extract "href" and "src" attribute values from HTML tags. You can use regex for that:

```
<(?:script|link)[^<]*?\s(?:src|href)=(?<quot>['"])(?<result>(?>(?!\k<quot>).)+)\k<quot>
```

Since we never know if single or double quotation marks are used in the HTML code, we can capture the first one (`(?<quot>['"])`), and then everything that is not equal to it (`(?<result>(?>(?!\k<quot>).)+)\k<quot>`).

You can split this into separate alternatives as well, named captured groups are great in C#:

```
<script[^<]*?\ssrc=(?<quot>['"])(?<result>(?>(?!\k<quot>).)+)\k<quot>|<link[^<]*?\shref=(?<quot>['"])(?<result>(?>(?!\k<quot>).)+)\k<quot>
```

**${result}** will hold your data.

Comment: i really like how you got the idea of what i was trying to do. I'd really appreciate any link to study regex for C#

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan: arco444's comment made me study your regex and it goes without saying regular expression is a viable solution here. As for learning, there is not much I can suggest: use regex tools (I am fond of Ultrapico's *Expresso*), experiment (I do it every day), and never give up (I do not do it every day :)). Good luck!